# SonarQube Version 5.6.4 Android Lint Profile not analysing xml files

Tags: android, sonarqube, lint, sonarqube-scan

All my java classes are being analysed with the Android Lint rules but not my xml.I have the xml plugin installed on sonarqube as well.
The sonarqube properties that i use are the following:

```
 sonarqube {
    properties {

        property "sonar.sources", "src"
        property "sonar.projectName", "XYZ" // Name of your project
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0.0" // Version of your project
        property "sonar.projectDescription", "XYZ Application"
        property "sonar.scm.provider","git"

    }
}
```

Somebody Help!!
P.S: I run the analysis by the command ./gradlew sonarqube

Answer (score 0):

Look at the new Android Lint Plugin - https://github.com/jvilya/sonar-android-plugin.

It should solve your issue.

Setup is easy

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.android.lint.reportPaths", "build/reports/lint-results.xml"
    }
}
```